# Define units in a netcdf file using python

Tags: python, unit-testing, netcdf, units-of-measurement

I am creating a netcdf file with a few variables. I got my netcdf file as useful as I expected but I don't know how define the units of my variables.

This is what my code looks like right now:

```
import netCDF4
import numpy as np

ncfile = netCDF4.Dataset('state.global.nc', 'r')
u = ncfile.variables['U'][:,:,:,:] # [T,Z,Y,X]
v = ncfile.variables['V'][:,:,:,:]
nx = np.shape(u)[3] - 1
ny = np.shape(v)[2] - 1
nz = np.shape(u)[1]

u_c = 0.5 * (u[:,:,:,0:nx] + u[:,:,:,1:nx+1])
v_c = 0.5 * (v[:,:,0:ny,:] + v[:,:,1:ny+1,:])

u_center = np.fliplr(u_c) # Flip upside down
v_center = np.fliplr(v_c)

# Write out u_center and v_center into a new netCDF file
ncfile_out = netCDF4.Dataset('./output.nc', 'w')
ncfile_out.createDimension('X', nx)
ncfile_out.createDimension('Y', ny)
ncfile_out.createDimension('Z', nz)

ncfile_out.createDimension('time', None)
u_out = ncfile_out.createVariable('u_center', 'f4', ('time', 'Z', 'Y', 'X'))
v_out = ncfile_out.createVariable('v_center', 'f4', ('time', 'Z', 'Y', 'X'))
time = ncfile_out.createVariable('Time', 'i4', 'time')

v_out.units = 'm/s' # Define units of variables
u_out.units = 'm/s'
time.units = 's'

u_out[:,:,:,:] = u_center[:,:,:,:]
v_out[:,:,:,:] = v_center[:,:,:,:]
ncfile_out.close()
```

But I read the final file using ncview and I don't see any units and I would like to define dimensions (x,y,z) units as 'meters' too. How can I do that? And, what if I want to put that 1 step in 'X' is something like '500 meters'?

Answer (score 2):

The way to define your units is with attributes in the netCDF file.

Although you can do this any way you like, the best idea is to stick with netCDF conventions and defined a text attribute called "units" for the variable, and put the SI units in.

There's a good example here:
http://schubert.atmos.colostate.edu/~cslocum/netcdf_example.html

Units are defined by code like this:

```
w_nc_var.setncatts({'long_name': u"mean Daily Air temperature",\
                'units': u"degK", 'level_desc': u'Surface',\
                'var_desc': u"Air temperature",\
                'statistic': u'Mean\nM'})
```

(The code above is also defining other attributes, but you can see it is setting 'units' to 'degK'.)

The udunits package can help if you need conversions between units. It's also a good place to get the abbreviation to use for your unit.

Udunits is also from Unidata, the same people who maintain netCDF.

http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/udunits/